# Stretch cases in order to be "more inclusive"

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, cases

Regarding the `dcases` environment, I noticed that, even if now I have all the math symbols extended (for example `frac`), when using derivatives the bracket doesn't actually cover completely the space needed from the math symbols.

Let's take the following example

[image]

given by the code

```
\[
    \begin{dcases}
        \frac{\partial U}{\partial l}\mathrm{d} l = 
        (\mathrm{d} U)_{\theta=\text{cost}} = \nabla U \cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l} = 
        -\nabla(\boldsymbol{E}_0 \cdot\boldsymbol{p})\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l}\\
        \\
        \frac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta = 
        \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(-E_0p\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta = 
        E_0p\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta =
        \boldsymbol{E}_0\times\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\theta}
    \end{dcases}
\]
```

As you can notice - if you don't, look at the next image - the derivatives escape the brace, even if for a microscopic portion.

[image]

Now, I understand it sounds like I'm a maniac, but this thing break the harmony of my LaTeX, so I'm desperately looking for a solution. 
I thought that it would be very nice if there were some options to the `dcases` environment to stretch a little bit more the cases, but if there're not such "facilities" how could it be solved?

Comment: That's normal and nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with egreg that it is nothing to worry about, but one could (and I did below) add a "strut" to the `\partial U` in the top equation and to the `\partial \theta` in the bottom equation.  As barbara notes, if the strut is a mere `\strut`, it may introduce a little unwanted vertical spacing, and so I define `\htstrut` to mask the depth and use it or `\strut` accordingly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tabstackengine}
\newcommand\htstrut{\setbox0=\hbox{\strut}\dp0=0pt}
\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{dcases}
        \frac{\partial U\htstrut}{\partial l}\mathrm{d} l = 
        (\mathrm{d} U)_{\theta=\text{cost}} = \nabla U \cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l} = 
        -\nabla(\boldsymbol{E}_0 \cdot\boldsymbol{p})\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l}\\
        \\
        \frac{\partial U}{\partial \theta\strut}\mathrm{d}\theta = 
        \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(-E_0p\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta = 
        E_0p\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta =
        \boldsymbol{E}_0\times\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\theta}
    \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, one could change the `dcases` to an `aligned`, place the data in the 2nd field of the `aligned`, then `\addstackgap[<length>]` to the `aligned`, and apply a `\left\{`.  In this case, no `\strut` is required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[
    \left\{\addstackgap[4pt]{\begin{aligned}
        &\frac{\partial U}{\partial l}\mathrm{d} l = 
        (\mathrm{d} U)_{\theta=\text{cost}} = \nabla U \cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l} = 
        -\nabla(\boldsymbol{E}_0 \cdot\boldsymbol{p})\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l}\\
        \\
        &\frac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}\mathrm{d}\theta = 
        \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(-E_0p\cos\theta)\mathrm{d}\theta = 
        E_0p\sin\theta\mathrm{d}\theta =
        \boldsymbol{E}_0\times\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\theta}
    \end{aligned}}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Above, I added a `4pt` gap above and below the `aligned` environment.  If I had chosen `8pt`, for example, it would have looked like this:

[image]

Comment: What's that `\strut`? What is for, and how did it fix the problem?

Comment: @opisthofulax A `\strut` is a zero-width thingie of finite total height equal to `\baselineskip`.  The height and depth of the `\strut` (above and below the baseline) is determined by the font itself, such that all glyphs of the font will always fall within the vertical footprint of the `\strut`.  Thus, the `\strut` will protrude higher than the `U` and lower than the `\theta`.  p.s.  I added a 2nd solution.

Comment: in your first paragraph, you really meant that, at the bottom, you added a `\strut` to `\partial\theta` instead of to `\partial U`.  however, do check the distance between the numerators of the initial fractions to make sure the distance between numerator and fraction line is exactly the same in both lines; i think there may be a slight increase in that space in the first line.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for noting that.  I have edited to use `\htstrut` if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You simply can use the `empheq` environment to do that. Needless to load `amsmath` since the former loads `mathtools`, which loads `amsmath`.

I also improved the spacing of you differentail symbol, defining a `\dd` command; and simplified the typing of partial differentials with the `esdiff` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq, esdiff}

\newcommand*{\dd}{\mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\mkern-2mu{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align*}
     & \diffp{U}{l}\dd l =
    (\dd U)_{\theta=\text{cost}} = \nabla U \cdot\dd \boldsymbol{l} =
    -\nabla(\boldsymbol{E}_0 \cdot\boldsymbol{p})\cdot\dd\boldsymbol{l}\\
    \\
    & \diffp{U}{\theta}\dd\theta =
    \diffp{}{\theta}(-E_0p\cos\theta)\dd\theta =
    E_0p\sin\theta\dd\theta =
    \boldsymbol{E}_0\times\boldsymbol{p}\cdot\dd\boldsymbol{\theta}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: in your second sentence, you probably want to change "it" to "`empheq`" since "it" makes it sound like `amsmath` loads `mathtools`, which loads ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton. You're right, it's ambiguous. I guess I wrote it this way because I don't like too many repetitions.