# Typeset a matrix with ellipses and \mathbb math alphabet

Tags: amsmath, matrices

I am looking for some help fixing my matrix. I am trying to make the J in my matrix look like the one in the first picture. Also I am trying to add ellipsis to my matrix like the first picture and take away some of the clutter, looking for some help, thanks!

[image]

[image]

Here's a MWE of the code I wrote.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} &\frac{\partial V_H}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial E_M} &      \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_M} \\     
\frac{\partial S_H}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial S_H}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial S_H}{\partial I_H} & \frac{\partial S_H}{\partial R_H} &  \frac{\partial S_H}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial S_H}{\partial E_M} &  \frac{\partial S_H}{\partial I_M} \\ 
\frac{\partial I_H}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial I_H}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial I_H}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial I_H}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial I_H}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial I_H}{\partial E_M} &  \frac{\partial I_H}{\partial I_M} \\ 
\frac{\partial R_H}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial R_H}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial R_H}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial R_H}{\partial R_H} &  \frac{\partial R_H}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial R_H}{\partial E_M} &  \frac{\partial R_H}{\partial I_M} \\ 
\frac{\partial S_M}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial S_M}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial S_M}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial S_M}{\partial R_H} &  \frac{\partial S_M}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial S_M}{\partial E_M} &  \frac{\partial S_M}{\partial I_M} \\  
\frac{\partial E_M}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial E_M}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial E_M}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial E_M}{\partial R_H} &  \frac{\partial E_M}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial E_M}{\partial E_M} &  \frac{\partial E_M}{\partial I_M} \\  
\frac{\partial I_M}{\partial V_H}    & \frac{\partial I_M}{\partial S_H} &  \frac{\partial I_M}{\partial I_H} &  \frac{\partial I_M}{\partial R_H} &  \frac{\partial I_M}{\partial S_M} &  \frac{\partial I_M}{\partial E_M} &  \frac{\partial I_M}{\partial I_M} 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried `\mathbb{J}`?

Comment: will try that now! thanks, how about the ellipsis?

Comment: seem to be getting a error for that

Comment: to use `\mathbb`, you need to `\usepackage{amsfonts}`.

Comment: The `unicode-math` package also defines `\mathbb` and practically every other math alphabet and symbol out there. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just missing the `amssymb` package in which is included the command `\mathbb{}`!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
        \mathbb{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} & \cdots & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} \\
            \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} &\frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} & \cdots & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} & \cdots & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \end{equation}

    %UNLABELLED VERSION
    \[
        \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
        \mathbb{J} = \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} & \cdots & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} \\
            \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} &\frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} & \cdots & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} \\
            \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_H} & \cdots & \frac{\partial V_H}{\partial R_H} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +100000 thanks so much for completing this fully

Comment: in my document it seems like this matrix is being labelled? why?

Comment: Because it is not in `\[...\]` but in `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, which is the environment for labelled equations.

Comment: could you edit and unlabel it?

Comment: That's a nice question and you should open a new topic for that, as it has to deal with the definition of the `bmatrix` environment in the package `amsmath`... I do not really know the answer, but I'm interested in the possible answer. Anyway if you're interested in a possible answer I've already asked for that [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381377/stretch-cases-in-order-to-be-more-inclusive) (in answer to the comment about the bottom spacing).

Comment: @user104 you should consider of choosing a best answer! If I was useful to you I would appreciate that `;-) `

Answer (score 6):

For the funny J load `amssymb` and type `\mathbb{J}`.

Also, do yourself a favor and define a command for the partial derivatives.

Final point, `\\[1ex]` gives some more breadth to the matrices, which is necessary here because of the big objects in them.

You had a missing `}` in one of the entries, which led to weird errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}

With ellipsis
\[
\mathbb{J} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\pder{f_1}{X_1} & \pder{f_1}{X_2} & \dots & \pder{f_1}{X_n} \\[1ex]
\pder{f_2}{X_1} & \pder{f_2}{X_2} & \dots & \pder{f_2}{X_n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\[1ex]
\pder{f_n}{X_1} & \pder{f_n}{X_2} & \dots & \pder{f_n}{X_n}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
and full
\[
\mathbb{J} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\pder{V_H}{V_H} & \pder{V_H}{S_H} & \pder{V_H}{I_H} & \pder{V_H}{R_H} &
  \pder{V_H}{S_M} & \pder{V_H}{E_M} & \pder{V_H}{I_M} \\[1ex]
\pder{S_H}{V_H} & \pder{S_H}{S_H} & \pder{S_H}{I_H} & \pder{S_H}{R_H} &
  \pder{S_H}{S_M} & \pder{S_H}{E_M} & \pder{S_H}{I_M} \\[1ex]
\pder{I_H}{V_H} & \pder{I_H}{S_H} & \pder{I_H}{I_H} & \pder{I_H}{I_H} &
  \pder{I_H}{S_M} & \pder{I_H}{E_M} & \pder{I_H}{I_M} \\[1ex]
\pder{R_H}{V_H} & \pder{R_H}{S_H} & \pder{R_H}{I_H} & \pder{R_H}{R_H} &
  \pder{R_H}{S_M} & \pder{R_H}{E_M} & \pder{R_H}{I_M} \\[1ex]
\pder{S_M}{V_H} & \pder{S_M}{S_H} & \pder{S_M}{I_H} & \pder{S_M}{R_H} &
  \pder{S_M}{S_M} & \pder{S_M}{E_M} & \pder{S_M}{I_M} \\[1ex]
\pder{E_M}{V_H} & \pder{E_M}{S_H} & \pder{E_M}{I_H} & \pder{E_M}{R_H} &
  \pder{E_M}{S_M} & \pder{E_M}{E_M} & \pder{E_M}{I_M} \\[1ex]
\pder{I_M}{V_H} & \pder{I_M}{S_H} & \pder{I_M}{I_H} & \pder{I_M}{R_H} &
  \pder{I_M}{S_M} & \pder{I_M}{E_M} & \pder{I_M}{I_M}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `\mathbb{J}` for the "J"; `\cdots` (horizontal dots),`\vdots` (vertical dots), and `\ddots` (diagonal dots) for the desired dots in the matrix.

Comment: I am getting an error from \mathbb{J}

Comment: You have to include the package `\usepackage{amssymb}`, to have the `\mathbb`...

Comment: @Qinyu Cui I would recommend `\cdots` for the horizontal dots, as they're more central, and so more coherent with the disposition of `\vdots`.

Comment: makes sense, edited.

Answer (score 3):

**edit:**
added dots as you ask me in comment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath, % <--- for "\mfrac", i.e. medium size "frac". it also load amsmath
            amssymb} % <--- for "\mathbb` font 

\begin{document}
\[\renewcommand\arraystretch{2} % <--- enlarge vertical space in matrix
\mathbb{J} =
\begin{bmatrix}
\mfrac{\partial V_H}{\partial V_H} & \mfrac{\partial V_H}{\partial S_H} &  \dotsm & \mfrac{\partial V_H}{\partial I_M} \\
\mfrac{\partial S_H}{\partial V_H} & \mfrac{\partial S_H}{\partial S_H} &  \dotsm & \mfrac{\partial S_H}{\partial I_M} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots       \\
\mfrac{\partial R_H}{\partial V_H} & \mfrac{\partial R_H}{\partial S_H} &  \dotsm & \mfrac{\partial R_H}{\partial I_M} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

*note:* for shorter writing you can define new command as proposed in [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) answer as

```
\newcommand{\pder}[2]{\mfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
```

Comment: could you edit in the dots?

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have already done a fine job of informing you that you need to load the `amssymb` package in order to access the `\mathbb` macro, so that you can write `\mathbb{J}`.

This answer provides a LuaLaTeX-based solution to the tedium of having to typeset the 7*7=49 elements (plus the `&` cell dividers and the `\\` end-of-line markers) of the full Jacobian matrix. The code given below sets up a Lua function called `jacobian_full`. The core of this function a pair of nested `for` loops, with each loop running over 7 elements. What's appealing about this approach is that once one has set up the code for a 7x7 matrix, it's trivial to go on to typesetting either larger or smaller Jacobian matrices. All one has to do is modify the elements of the `vars` vector.

With this approach, there is but a single statement -- `\directlua{jacobian_full()}` -- between the `\begin{bmatrix}` and `\end{bmatrix}` statements. Compare this to the 2*49=98  directives (don't forget to count all those `&` and `\\` directives!) that are needed in the standard approach.

---

This approach to typesetting the full 7x7 matrix may also be employed to typeset a "truncated" 4x4 matrix, in which the third row and third column are filled with suitably-oriented typographic ellipses ("triple dots"). The only thing that's substantially different between the Lua functions `jacobian_full` and `jacobian_abbrv` is that the former contains the single line

```
tex.sprint ( "\\pder{" .. vars[i] .."}{" .. vars[j] .."}" )
```

whereas in `jacobian_abbrv`, this single line gets replaced by a group of `if` statements, where the line above gets output only if the row and column indices `i` and `j` are both not equal to `3`. If either `i` or `j` is equal to `3`, `\cdots`/`\vdots`/`\ddots` is output, as appropriate.

---

[image]

```
% !TeX program=lualatex

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

%% Place the Lua code in an external file
\begin{filecontents*}{jacobians.lua}
```

```lua
-- Function to output "&" or "\\" after each cell
function cell_terminate ( i,j,N )
  if j<N then
    tex.sprint ( "&" )
  elseif i<N then
    tex.sprint ( "\\\\" )
  end
end

-- Function to print the full Jacobian matrix
function jacobian_full()
  -- Modify the following Lua table as needed:
  vars = { "V_H","S_H","I_H","R_H","S_M","E_M","I_M" }
  for i = 1,#vars do
    for j = 1,#vars do
      tex.sprint ("\\pder{"..vars[i].."}{"..vars[j].."}")
      cell_terminate(i,j,#vars)
    end
  end
end

-- Function to print the abbreviated Jacobian matrix
function jacobian_abbrv()
  -- Third element of 'vars' is arbitrary:
  vars = { "V_H", "S_H", "xyz", "I_M" }
  for i = 1,#vars do
    for j = 1,#vars do
      if i==3 and not (j==3) then 
        tex.sprint ("\\vdots")
      elseif j==3 and not (i==3) then
        tex.sprint ("\\cdots")
      elseif i==3 and j==3 then
        tex.sprint ("\\ddots")  
      else
        tex.sprint ("\\pder{"..vars[i].."}{"..vars[j].."}")
      end
      cell_terminate(i,j,#vars)
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathbb' macro
\newcommand\pder[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\directlua{dofile 'jacobians.lua'} % load the Lua code

\begin{document}
%% Print the full and abbreviated Jacobians
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{gather*}
\mathbb{J}  = \begin{bmatrix} 
                 \directlua{ jacobian_full() } 
              \end{bmatrix} \\[3ex]
\mathbb{J}' = \begin{bmatrix} 
                 \directlua{ jacobian_abbrv() } 
              \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose this solution, which uses the `esdiff` package to simplify the typing of partial derivatives, and `makecell` to add some padding to the rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{array, makecell}

\begin{document}

\[%
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\mathbb{J} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \diffp{V_H}{{{V_H}}} & \diffp{V_H}{{{S_H}}} & \diffp{V_H}{{{I_H}}} & \diffp{V_H}{{{R_H}}} & \cdots &\diffp{V_H}{{{S_M}}} & \diffp{V_H}{{{E_M}}} & \diffp{V_H}{{I_M}} \\
\diffp{S_H}{{V_H}} & \diffp{S_H}{{S_H}} & \diffp{S_H}{{I_H}} & \diffp{S_H}{{R_H}} & \cdots & \diffp{S_H}{{S_M}} & \diffp{S_H}{{E_M}} & \diffp{S_H}{{I_M}} \\
 \diffp{I_H}{{V_H}} & \diffp{I_H}{{S_H}} & \diffp{I_H}{{I_H}} & \diffp{I_H}{{I_H}} & \cdots & \diffp{I_H}{{S_M}} & \diffp{I_H}{{E_M}} & \diffp{I_H}{{I_M}} \\
\diffp{R_H}{{V_H}} & \diffp{R_H}{{S_H}} & \diffp{R_H}{{I_H}} & \diffp{R_H}{{R_H}} & \cdots & \diffp{R_H}{{S_M}} & \diffp{R_H}{{E_M}} & \diffp{R_H}{{I_M}} \\[-6pt]
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & \cdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\[-13.66pt]
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\vdots & & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\[-1pt]
 \diffp{S_M}{{V_H}} & \diffp{S_M}{{S_H}} & \diffp{S_M}{{I_H}} & \diffp{S_M}{{R_H}} & \cdots& \diffp{S_M}{{S_M}} & \diffp{S_M}{{E_M}} & \diffp{S_M}{{I_M}} \\
 \diffp{E_M}{{V_H}} & \diffp{E_M}{{S_H}} & \diffp{E_M}{{I_H}} & \diffp{E_M}{{R_H}} & \cdots & \diffp{E_M}{{S_M}} & \diffp{E_M}{{E_M}} & \diffp{E_M}{{I_M}} \\
\diffp{I_M}{{V_H}} & \diffp{I_M}{{S_H}} & \diffp{I_M}{{I_H}} & \diffp{I_M}{{R_H}} & \cdots & \diffp{I_M}{{S_M}} & \diffp{I_M}{{E_M}} & \diffp{I_M}{{I_M}}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]